# Does my method supports multiple http post requests at a time?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a post method like below which work fine with manual postings either from postman or UI (Angular).

For a test purpose, as if 100 users posting at a time, I trid to post to this method from an Angular event with a loop of 100 times.

First One or Two iterations are successful and then all remaining iterations gets Internal Server Error.

My data is very simple and does not have PK/FK or any other type of constraints in it. When I repeat click event, it again stores one or two iterations then again same Internal Server Error.

C# Method

```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> PostControlName([FromBody] MyClass myClass)
    {
        _context.MyTable.Add(myClass);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync()
        return Ok();    
    }
```

Angular Method

```
post(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('https://localhost:44303/api/ControlName', data);
  }

myMethod() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    // all myForm properties have default values
    this.post(this.myForm.value).subscribe( dd => { this.saved++; });
  }
}
```

> Http failure response for https://localhost:44303/api/ControlName:
>   500 OK

I use `Asp.Net Core 2.2`, `Angular8`
Do I need to do any changes in my code to supports multiple requests at a time?

[image]

Comment: A `500 OK` response is highly unusual. You have some other code causing this.

Comment: Triggering single http post on a button click 100 times with the same form values working and storing in db. But when I loop with i get this error.